# Making opaque an itemized list after a pause command

Tags: beamer, itemize, pause, transparent

I'm working on a presentation with beamer. I have an itemized list after a `\pause` command and I would like that the whole list appeared opaque before each item is revealed one by one. However, the list does not appear opaque (it does not appear at all). More strangely, the text after the list appears opaque without problems. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{frame}{Title}

    \pause

    Some text

    \pause

    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item First
        \item Second
        \item Third
    \end{itemize}

    \pause[\thebeamerpauses]

    Other text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Below is how it appears.

[image: undesired behavior]

Below is how I wish it would appears.

[image: desired behavior]

Comment: @cabohah fixed! Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list does appear, its transparency is just higher than the other uncovered text as the transparency is adding up (the list both gets transparency from the pause and the overlays). A clumsy workaround would be to make sure it is uncovered on the first 2 slides so it only gets the transparency from the pause:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}

    \pause

    Some text

    \pause

    \begin{itemize}[<1-2,+->]
        \item First
        \item Second
        \item Third
    \end{itemize}

    \pause[\thebeamerpauses]

    Other text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However you can avoid the problem more elegantly by not using pause, it is anyway a very crude command and you'll get more flexibility out of beamer's other overlay macros:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}

    \only<+>{}\uncover<+->{Some text}

    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item First
        \item Second
        \item Third
    \end{itemize}

    \uncover<+->{other text}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you insist on using pauses, you could redefine some beamer internals (no guarantee that this won't break other stuff....):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@startcovered{%
  \beamer@smuggle{%
  \global\advance\beamer@coveringdepth by 1\relax%
  \beamer@actions{\pgfsys@begininvisible\aftergroup\beamer@@spacingcover}{%
     \pgfsys@endinvisible\aftergroup\beamer@@spacingcover%
     }%
  \def\opaqueness<##1>##2{%
    \only<##1>{%
      \beamer@actions{%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname beamer@oldcolorhook%
        \the\beamer@coveringdepth\endcsname{\beamer@colorhook}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname beamer@oldpgfextension%
        \the\beamer@coveringdepth\endcsname{\beamer@pgfextension}%
        {\globalcolorstrue\colorlet{beamer@freeze\the\beamer@coveringdepth}{bg}}%
        \xdef\beamer@colorhook{!##2!}%
        \gdef\beamer@pgfextension{!##2opaque}%
        \color{.}%
      }%
      {%
        \xdef\beamer@colorhook{\csname beamer@oldcolorhook%
          \the\beamer@coveringdepth\endcsname}%
        \xdef\beamer@pgfextension{\csname beamer@oldpgfextension%
          \the\beamer@coveringdepth\endcsname}%
        \color{.}%
      }}}%
  \ifnum\beamer@slideinframe<\beamer@minimum %ok, at beginning
    \begingroup
      \beamer@saveanother
      \advance\beamer@minimum by-\beamer@slideinframe
      \beamer@slideinframe=\beamer@minimum
      \beamer@uncoverbeforeactions
      \beamer@restoreanother
    \endgroup
  \else
    \begingroup
      \beamer@saveanother
      \advance\beamer@slideinframe by-\beamer@minimum
      \beamer@uncoverafteractions
      \beamer@restoreanother
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \beamer@do
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

    \pause

    Some text

    \pause

    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item First
        \item Second
        \item Third
    \end{itemize}

    \pause[\thebeamerpauses]

    Other text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the issue with your approaches is that I have to manually insert the slide numbers (and then change them if a move some stuff around). I was hoping for a "slide numbers"-free solution similar to my original code. Would it be possible? You mentioned that "the transparency is adding up." Maybe this behavior can be customized so that the transparency saturates to a prescribed value?

Comment: @rosan98 Use my second approach, it is 100% slide number free

Comment: Thank again. Unfortunately I still have an issue with your proposed "slide numbers"-free solution. I already have many slides written in the style of my first post. Is there any hope to make transparency works with my pause-style (for example by saturating it somehow), or I have to manually change to something like you proposed solution?

Comment: @rosan98 I added a version for pauses

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!